# mnesia dir setting in emacs for mnesia cluster testing

Tags: emacs, erlang

When testing cluster mnesia in one pc, I have to create many erlang nodes for one "Mac lion" user.
Because they share the same `".erlang"` for the same user, so I can't pass the mnesia through `".erlang"` file.
For the emacs erlang shell, I want to pass the mnesia directory configuration through `.emacs` file, so the distel's related escript codes should be modified.

```
(add-hook 'erlang-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        ;; when starting an Erlang shell in Emacs, default in the node name
        ; (setq inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-name" "emacs"))
        (setq inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-name" "emacs""-mnesia dir" "/Users/yuchen/Documents/Project/mnesia_db") )
             ;;added by chenyu 2012/04/08 
             (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command) (format "make -f %s" (get-closest-pathname)))
        ;; add Erlang functions to an imenu menu
        (imenu-add-to-menubar "imenu")))
```

In the above code, `name=emacs` is ok, but `mnesia dir` is not effective.

(setq inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-name" "emacs""-mnesia dir" "/Users/yuchen/Documents/Project/mnesia_db") )

After the node is up, I have checked the mnesia path configuration.

```
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)12> mnesia:system_info(directory).
"/Users/yuchen/Mnesia.emacs@yus-iMac.local"
```

It is not same as my .emacs configuration data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that you need to put `-mnesia` and `dir` in separate strings in the list of arguments, and you need to wrap the directory in double quotes as well, which of course you'd have to escape in Emacs Lisp:

```
(setq inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-name" "emacs" "-mnesia" "dir" "\"/Users/yuchen/Documents/Project/mnesia_db\"") )
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tested it. But after testing, command "mnesia:info()" always show "===> System info in version "4.6", debug level = none <===
opt_disc. Directory "/Users/yuchen/Mnesia.emacs@yus-iMac.local" is used.".

Comment: Hm, I just tested it myself, and for me `mnesia:info` displays the directory specified in the variable.  Not sure what might be different... Perhaps you could check with `C-h v` that `inferior-erlang-machine-options` is really set to what you expect it to be?

Comment: Hi, the c-h, v shown that "Its value is ("-name" "emacs")". It seems that this line of modification has still some little mistake. I will test it more. Thank you very much.